# Creating an http to https conversion forward proxy in golang with built in http package

Tags: go, https, proxy

I am a beginner in Golang and couldn't find a straightforward way to implement this. I have a use case where the backend servers must use a proxy to talk to front end servers, where some of the front end servers support only https.

I was thinking of using two ports, one that forwards as HTTP and the other HTTPS. The backend always talks to the proxy via HTTP. Is there a better way to do this?

My current proxy server is not doing the http to https conversion. It still uses HTTP and I couldn't figure out why?

```
    egressClient := &http.Client{
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
                },
            },
        }
    
    html, err := egressClient.Transport.RoundTrip(r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        website, err := ioutil.ReadAll(html.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        html.Body.Close()
        log.Print(string(website))
```

Where the `r` is the HTTP request obtained from the backend. I must forward r as an HTTPS request.

Comment: Have you tried to change `r.URL.Scheme` to `"https"`?

Comment: I tried this out and this has indeed solved the problem. With the scheme set to HTTPS, the requests are now being sent as HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the `r.URL.Scheme = "https"` as @leaf bebop suggested in comments has solved the issue. With the scheme set to HTTPS, the requests are now being sent as HTTPS.

---

Helpful references:

https://posener.github.io/http2/ Suggested by @Amrendra Yadav,
[HTTP/2 Cleartext (H2C) Client](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/http-2-cleartext-h2c-client-example-go/#:%7E:text=HTTP%2F2%20Cleartext%20(H2C)%20Client%20Example%20in%20Go,-Derrick%20Wippler&text=First%2C%20in%20case%20you%20may,HTTP%2F2%20but%20without%20TLS.&text=H2C%20support%20only%20exists%20in,handler%20or%20mux%20with%20h2c.) and [How to play Go Lang with HTTP](https://medium.com/@ldclakmal/how-to-play-go-lang-with-http-5f3628e81001)

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog explains much about the http and https in golang. You can go through this: https://posener.github.io/http2/